# Ajax fill array with objects from php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to make an Ajax call to PHP and get a javascript array like this structure.

Example:

```
var coordinate = [
{lat: 22.5, lng: 13.1},
{lat: 22.7, lng: 14.5},
{lat: 23.8, lng: 13.5}
];
```

How can I iterate through the response of the PHP to get this?

Comment: With `json_encode` function.

Comment: "How can I iterate through the response of the PHP to get this?"  ... you should read up on javascript and arrays and objects. Do some research before asking such a broad question with little to no effort shown for it.

Comment: Is there any **relevant** reason for your case to perform an http request or is it just for research purposes? Besides, there are like a billion questions like this one here and there, you should first look at these ;). That said, you should provide what you have tried to accomplish the issue, otherwise it's easy to consider such a question as off topic. Please read the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode`, passing an array as a parameter. Look:

```
<?php
   echo json_encode([
     ['lat' => 22.5, 'lng' => 13.1],
     ['lat' => 22.7, 'lng' => 14.5],
     ['lat' => 23.8, 'lng' => 13.5]
   ]);
```

This will return a string, in JSON format. If the AJAX request is being made with JQuery, no parse is required. But if you're natively calling, you'll want to use the `JSON.parse` method of JavaScript that will take the string in JSON and convert it to JavaScript object.

Hope this helps!